# ASP.NET – jQuery is not Working in UpdatePanels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I am unable call jQuery functions within "asp:UpdatePanel". As per the code given below I want to add a class on div element ".popup-body" but its not working. On the other side "alert();" works.

My jQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".popup-body .btn").click(function () {
        //alert("it works");
        $(this).closest(".popup-body").addClass("loading-content");
    });
});
```

My HTML:

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="testDiv">test div</div>
            <div class="popup-body" id="divBody" runat="server">
                <div class="textbox">
                    <label>First Name:</label>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFname" />
                </div>
                <div class="footer">
                    <asp:Button Text="Save" CssClass="btn" ID="btnSave" runat="server" />
                    <asp:Button Text="Clear" CssClass="btn" runat="server" ID="btnClear" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I have read many articles and tried different solutions like following, but failed

```
// JavaScript funciton to call inside UpdatePanel
    function jScript() {
        $("#click").click(function () {
            alert("Clicked Me!");
        });
    }
//Code placed within "asp:updatepanel"
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            Sys.Application.add_load(jScript);
</script>
```

Comment: can you try with `$(document).on("click", ".popup-body .btn" , function () {` instead of your `$(".popup-body .btn").click(function () {`

Comment: Hi @vijayP, I have a new scenario here to trigger the popup by clicking the anchor button inside the iframe. Let me create a new Question to avoid any confusion

Comment: Here it is:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39095879/asp-net-jquery-is-not-working-after-postback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UpdatePanel` renders a completely new DOM-element on postback. Therefore the event-listener will be lost everytime the `UpdatePanel` makes a postback or updates.

To avoid this you can bind to a element higher up in the dom by using [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of [`.click`](https://api.jquery.com/click/).

```
$("body").on("click", ".popup-body .btn", function () {
    //alert("it works");
    $(this).closest(".popup-body").addClass("loading-content");
});
```

In the example above we bind to `body` instead. But you can bind to a element closer to `.popup-body`.

```
<div class="my-container">
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="testDiv">test div</div>
            <div class="popup-body" id="divBody" runat="server">
                <div class="textbox">
                    <label>First Name:</label>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFname" />
                </div>
                <div class="footer">
                    <asp:Button Text="Save" CssClass="btn" ID="btnSave" runat="server" />
                    <asp:Button Text="Clear" CssClass="btn" runat="server" ID="btnClear" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

And bind to the container outside of `UpdatePanel`.

```
$(".my-container").on("click", ".popup-body .btn", function () {
    //alert("it works");
    $(this).closest(".popup-body").addClass("loading-content");
});
```