# ASP.NET – jQuery is not Working after Postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, iframe, onclick

Function works one time only but fails when page loads after `Postback`. Am I missing something with `onclick` method?

My HTML:

```
        <!-- Iframe Section -->
        <div class="rmpView" id="ContentPlaceHolder1">
            <iframe src="/Tabs/tabOne.aspx?ID=0" height="500" width="100%">

                <html>
                    <head></head>
                    <body>
                        <div id="wrapper-iframe">
                            <label>Name:</label>
                            <input type="text"/>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-target="dBoxPopup" class="btn">Open Popup</a>
                        </div>
                    </body>
                </html>

            </iframe>
        </div>
        <!-- Iframe Section ENDS -->

        <!-- Popup body -->
        <div id="dBoxPopup" class="dialog-box">
            <uc1:wucPopupContent runat="server" ID="wucPopupContent" />
        </div>
        <!-- Popup body ENDS -->
```

My jQuery:

```
$("#ContentPlaceHolder1 iframe").load(function (e) {
    // trigger popup onclick inside the iframe BEGINS
    $(this).contents().find('.btn').on("click", function () {
        var btnHref = $(this).attr("data-target");
        javascript: popup(btnHref)
    });
    // trigger popup onclick inside the iframe ENDS
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One reason could be that after the post back, the button is not able to be found. If this is the case, the popup will not be invoked since the button itself is not present.